# How to instantiate the helper class in my phtml in Magento2

Tags: magento2

In my Module, i just have a Block.

I am not using any Controller in my custom module.

In my phtml template i need to call helper class like below, We used to call in Magento1.

```
  $params =$this->getRequest()->getParams();  
  $helper = Mage::helper("My Helper class");  //Here how to instantiate the helper in my phtml
  $filters = $helper->getmydata();
  $res = $helper->getSearchData();
```

How can i use helper in phtml in Magento2.

Answer (score 6):

We can call helper class in template file like

```
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
```

use $_helper object to call helper method.

Answer (score 3):

You can call your module helper in **phtml** like this

```
$this->helper('YourNamespace\Modulename\Helper\Data')->helperfunctionname();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call helper in your block

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Company1\Module1\Helper\Data $helper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
```

Use `$block->helper` in your Template.